# Como editar valores em uma coluna?

Tags: r

Ola, tenho um dataset com as seguintes colunas

```
date          total_cases
2019-12-31       0      
2020-01-01       0      
2020-01-02       0      
2020-01-03       0      
2020-01-04       0      
2020-01-05       0
```

estou tentando tirar os dias e deixar somente o ano e o mes, e entao irei uni-los usando a função aggregate.
podem me dar uma dica de alguma forma de eu fazer esse procedimento?

Obs: importei os dados da seguinte forma

```
dados = read.csv(file = "raw_data.csv", sep = ",", na.strings = "", strip.white = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez isso te ajude

```
library(lubridate)

df$dia <- day(df$date)
df$ano_mes <- paste0(year(date),'-',month(date))
```

Utilizando o pacote lubridate conseguimos extrair o dia, mês e ano.
Neste caso eu criei novas colunas no data frame mas você pode fazer de outra forma se preferir.

Saída

```
        date total_cases dia ano_mes
1 2019-12-31           0  31 2019-12
2 2020-01-01           0   1  2020-1
3 2020-01-02           0   2  2020-1
4 2020-01-03           0   3  2020-1
5 2020-01-04           0   4  2020-1
6 2020-01-05           0   5  2020-1
```

---

Pode também extrair um a um e colocar em novas colunas

```
df2$dia <- day(df2$date)
df2$mes <- month(df2$date)
df2$ano <- year(df2$date)
```

Saída

```
        date total_cases dia mes  ano
1 2019-12-31           0  31  12 2019
2 2020-01-01           0   1   1 2020
3 2020-01-02           0   2   1 2020
4 2020-01-03           0   3   1 2020
5 2020-01-04           0   4   1 2020
6 2020-01-05           0   5   1 2020
```